# changing counter value inside a list all the the values changes getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I need to create a separate widget consists of **{add button, text form form, minus button}**. i need the user if click these buttons, the value of the text form field changes. also if the user tap the text input field enter his own number. i am using GetX. i am using this separate widget with its own controller. the problem is i am using this widget inside list view, when the user change the value of the counter all the text input field inside the list view changes. i created an specific id for each builder and tell the function of the controller to be changed only when this specific id called. so the expected output that the value of text input field that the user changed be changed only, but all the values inside the list view changed too.

**The Counter Code Is:**

```
class CounterController extends GetxController {
  
  late TextEditingController counterController;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // make initial value is 0
    counterController = TextEditingController(text: "0");
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    counterController.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }

  /// increase the value of the counter
  void increaseCounter({required String counterID}) {
    counterController.text = (int.parse(counterController.text) + 1).toString();
    update([counterID]);
  }

  /// decrease the value of the counter
  void decreaseCounter({required String counterID}) {
    if (int.parse(counterController.text) != 0) {
      counterController.text =
          (int.parse(counterController.text) - 1).toString();
    update([counterID]);

    } else {
      Get.snackbar(
        "error",
        "value can not be negative",
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**The Code of UI inside the list view is:**

```
 Flexible(
                child: GetBuilder<CounterController>(
                    id: counterID,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return TextField(
                        controller: controller.counterController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        cursorColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: DARK_GREY_COLOR,
                          fontSize: screen.isPhone ? 20 : 40,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
                          fillColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
                          focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: PRIMARY_COLOR),
                          ),
                        ),
                        inputFormatters: [
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem you mentioned, it seems like you're using same TextEditingController for multiple TextFields. Just as you're using different IDs for get builders, you need to use separate TextEditingControllers for each TextField as well.